# Correct Way to Use this in a controller

Tags: angularjs

I heard in a blog that an easy way to prepare for Angular 2.0 is to not use **$scope** inside a controller, but use **this** instead. I have found that **this** used inside a function that is inside a controller is not the **this** that should be the **$scope**

**FAILS**

```
var loginControllerId = 'loginCtrl';
app.controller(loginControllerId, ['$scope',function ($scope) {
    this.login = {};
    function myFunc(){
        // FAILS - this.login is undefined I think because "this" is now referring to the myFunc function
        this.login.message = "Some Message"; 
    }
    this.login.successMessage = "Success";  // PASSES        
});
```

What I think is a work around is to create a var and set **this ($scope)** to it. Can somebody tell me if this is a good way to do this or if there is a different method to globally use the controllers **this**?

**PASSES**

```
var loginControllerId = 'loginCtrl';
app.controller(loginControllerId, ['$scope',function ($scope) {
    var loginScope = this;
    loginScope.login = {};
    function myFunc(){
        // PASSES
        loginScope.login.message = "Some Message"; 
    }
    loginScope.login.successMessage = "Success";  // PASSES        
});
```

Comment: look at the [controller as method](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its common to use something like `var vm = this;` in your controller. See the very popular [styleguide by John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y032).

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use angular extend

```
function MainCtrl () {
  angular.extend(this, {
    someVar: {
      name: 'Todd'
    },
    anotherVar: [],
    doSomething: function doSomething() {

    }
  });
}
```

Take a look at this post for full explanation

https://toddmotto.com/a-better-way-to-scope-angular-extend-no-more-vm-this/